# Is there a way to run the sql script with execute statement without declaring a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a primary table in my db as below

[image]

Also I have 6 tables in my db namely Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, Table_4, Table_5 and Table_6 (with all same columns) . Example shown below

[image]

Now, I want to combine tables where i have a condition. Condition is whenever primary_table has a consider 'Yes', only then that number is considered. In this example 2,3 and 4 from primary_table (number column) are considered so Table_2,Table_3 and Table_4 are taken and combined.

I have a written a query(say Q1.sql) for this and this works fine. But the issue is after I execute Q1.sql, i need to copy paste that contents into another window and then execute.

Q1.sql below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
@table_name nvarchar(max) = 'TABLE_'

DECLARE @table_variable table (id int identity(1,1), num int)

insert into
@table_variable
select number from primary_table where consider in ('Yes')

declare @intflag int,
@nrows int,
@tab1 nvarchar(max),
@dec_var nvarchar(max) = '',
@uni nvarchar(max) = ''

select @nrows = count(number) from primary_table where consider in ('Yes')
set @intflag = 0 
while (@intflag <= @nrows)

begin 

select @tab1 = concat(@dec_var, Char(13), N' if (Exists (
Select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in (''',@table_name,num,'''))) BEGIN insert into @tabs select col1 from ',@table_name,num, ' END', CHAR(13), @uni)
from @table_variable where id = @intflag
   set @intflag = @intflag + 1
   set @uni = case
              when @intflag < @nrows then ''
              when @intflag >= @nrows then 'select * from @tabs'
              end 
              set @dec_var = case 
                        when @intflag = 1 then 'Declare @tabs table (col1 int)'
                        when @intflag >= @nrows then ''
                        end 
              print (@tab1)

END 
GO 
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

After I execute above , i get below

```
 
Declare @tabs table (col1 int)
 if (Exists (
Select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in ('TABLE_2'))) BEGIN insert into @tabs select col1 from TABLE_2 END


 if (Exists (
Select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in ('TABLE_3'))) BEGIN insert into @tabs select col1 from TABLE_3 END


 if (Exists (
Select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in ('TABLE_4'))) BEGIN insert into @tabs select col1 from TABLE_4 END
select * from @tabs
```

Then I Need to copy the above contents in another window and then execute.
My question is , the moment I execute Q1.sql, I need to get the output (there is no need to copy the contents in another window). However I tried to replace `print (@tab1)` with `exec(@tab1)`,but getting error .

Can anyone help? Not sure what wrong I am doing here

Comment: I acknowledge this is outside the scope of the question as you've posed it here, but is there a reason why you've got `TABLE_X` when they all have the same schema instead of including each of them in the same table with an additional identifier (i.e., `source`)? That would make this operation significantly easier for you.

Comment: Please do not post jpegs in your question.

Comment: I think you should use partitioning instead of multiple tables with the same schema.

Comment: On the contrary, the very existence of those tables *is* the problem. Why do they exist at all? If you wanted to partition a big table you could use ... partitioning. Even if there's a legitimate reason to have different identical tables, you can combine all of them in a view with `UNION ALL` and query all of them as one. If the tables have proper constraints, the query optimizer may be able to pick and query only a few of the tables instead of all of them

Comment: guys, I was expecting a solution here :) Not other way to execute this. I know there are manual ways to write the query. The sample here is just an example. I have a same issue with complex dataset and it is impossible to post it here. The question here is simple, When I am able to run the query with ```` print (@tab1)```` but why not with ```` exec (@tab1)```` ?  That is it. Did my question makes sense :)

Comment: Presumably when you print it you get multiple different strings that when combined are valid. When you are `exec`-ing it in the loop you are trying to execute invalid fragments

Comment: First, a long description ending with "...but getting error" does not give us much to go on. Without the complete error message, we don't have a starting point for debugging a convoluted process. Might the error be something like "**Msg 1087 ..., Must declare the table variable "@tabs**"? That would have given us a critical clue. It turns out your loop generates separate statements for each iteration. Iteration 0 generates `Declare @tabs ...`. The next iteration generates an `insert into @tab`. The problem is, **table variables do not persist** across different `EXEC` executions.

Comment: Since this question is closed, I cannot post a new answer, but if you look at [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wj5qNCT1) you will see a much simplified version that generates a single dynamic SQL statement to accomplish your goal. The *table-exists* check is combined with the `consider = 'Yes'` filter. The `STRING_AGG()` function is used to combine all dynamic SQL into a single batch. (A `FOR XML` alternative is provided for older SQL Server versions.) The results are routed to a `#temp` table instead of a `@table` variable, so it can be shared between the calling and EXEC environments.

Comment: If the source tables being selected and combined are large, this technique for combining data can be extremely inefficient and wasteful if run repeatedly or merged into another frequently run query or process.  I agree with the others that this reflects a bad database design. I would suggest that you go to whoever designed this data and (1) ask then to fix it, and (2) never design data like this again for the remainder of their professional careers. If someone is teaching SQL and designing data like this, it is even more important that they stop and never do this again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for such complex code, or for dynamic SQL.

You can just union the tables together and then join on the result.

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM primary_table pt
JOIN (
    SELECT id, 1 AS tblNumber
    FROM table_1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 2 AS tblNumber
    FROM table_2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 3 AS tblNumber
    FROM table_3

    UNION ALL

    ... etc
) t ON t.tblNumber = pt.id AND pt.consider = 'Yes';
```

Consider redesigning your database so that all the tables are in one in the first place.

Comment: YOur is not dynamic and the user needs to write all tables.. What is tables increases in the db.. Example Table_1  ....... till Table_100 ? Should the user write will Table_100?

Comment: Just copy and paste it. At the very least, use a better dynamic SQL generator, such as `STRING_AGG` with `sys.tables`